# How to synchronize all Brave Browser data to a new Mac (without Migration Assistant)?

Tags: data-synchronization

I have tried syncing all of my Brave Browser data (cookies, settings, extensions, extension settings, history, cache) from an old Mac to a new Mac like so:

```bash
rsync --archive --relative --delete --checksum --verbose \
    ~/./'Library/Application Support/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser' \
    ~/./'Library/Preferences/com.brave.Browser.plist' \
    ~/./'Library/Caches/BraveSoftware' \
    ~/./'Library/Saved Application State/com.brave.Browser.savedState' \
    user@newmac:
```

Which succeeds, with the following careful considerations

1. The `rsync` parameters guarantee that the owner, permissions, file paths, and files are all identical between both machines. There are no missing files, extra files, or different versions of files.
2. The `uid` and `gid` of the user and groups for these files are identical on both machines, I checked.
3. The version of Brave is the same on both machines, from Homebrew:
   `Version 1.49.120 Chromium: 111.0.5563.64 (Official Build)`
4. Brave was closed on both machines during the transfer

**However, when I open Brave on the new machine, the cookies are clearly not working because nothing is logged in, and all of the settings for extensions has been deleted by Brave because it thinks they're corrupted.**

**Are there any other paths that I missed?**

I also asked this question at [Brave Community](https://community.brave.com):

- [Brave Community: ​How to sync all Brave Browser data to a new Mac (without Migration Assistant)?](https://community.brave.com/t/how-to-sync-all-brave-browser-data-to-a-new-mac-without-migration-assistant/477809)

Comment: Answer coming soon, but you basically have to sync your keychain at `~/Library/Keychains`, but it's not trivially simple to do it correctly.